# Can I move the delete the swap partition in an existing installation?

Tags: partitioning, gparted, swap

I'm just learning best practices on partitioning. I want to move my swap partition to the right end of my disk.

[partitions screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWqw3.png)

Am I not breaking anything if I delete the swap? How about it being partition number 3?

Comment: You can't MOVE the swap partition, as there are 3 partitions in the way. You'd have to delete it, recreate it, find out the new UUID, and update /etc/fstab and /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume. And yes, just deleting swap will break it. Also, we don't support Kali here. Sorry.

Comment: I have never had a problem adding or removing a swap partition, just make sure /etc/fstab is up to date.

Comment: Just be sure the free command says zero bytes of swap used before deleting it.

Comment: @ubfan1 just checking for zero swap used, and deleting swap, isn't the right way to do it. You'd first issue a swapoff command.

Comment: I still dont get why this is a duplicate question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my question as I was able to resolve it in a manner that I think I'm satisfied. Please feel free to correct me if wrong. I want other's to get this same question answered the easiest and clearest way possible.

As mentioned, I had Ubuntu 18.10 already running fine. I had this setup.

- Partition 1 - efi
- Partition 2 - ubuntu /
- Partition 3 - swap
- Partition 4 - ubuntu /home
- Partition 5 - kali /home
- Partition 6 - kali /
- free space

I went to Kali and used GParted. I was able to delete Partition 3. I added Partition 7 for swap at the end of free space. I tried booting on Ubuntu and it proceeded.

- Partition 1 - efi
- Partition 2 - ubuntu /
- Partition 3 - free space
- Partition 4 - ubuntu /home
- Partition 5 - kali /home
- Partition 6 - kali /
- free space
- Partition 7 - swap

What I noticed is that in Ubuntu, no swap is being used. So I just used the built-in Disks app, then enabled swap.

Then to check, I did

`sudo swapon --show`

and got this:

```
NAME      TYPE      SIZE USED PRIO
/dev/sdc7 partition 7.5G   0B   -2
```

Something to note, since I'm working on a third disk, the naming scheme is 
sdc1, sdc2 then sdc4. The deleted swap file entailed sdc3 'label/tag' to be missing.

Does this mean sdc3 wont be used anymore as a label/tag?

```
sdc             119.2G                               
├─sdc1 vfat        94M /boot/efi                     
├─sdc2 ext4      13.5G / 
freespace                            
├─sdc4 ext4       3.6G /home                         
├─sdc5 ext4       3.7G                               
├─sdc6 ext4      14.9G
freespace                              
└─sdc7 swap       7.5G [SWAP]
```

Also, if I add another partition on the second freespace, will the numeric partition naming scheme stay the same? i.e. sdc7 will stick at the end of the disk or will there be a rearrangement of name?

What's the implication of losing sdc3?

Comment: See my original comment to your question.

Comment: I did. @heynnema